# FB graph API on iOS: FBGraphPlace in FBGraphUser is always nil

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm (sucesfully) searching for FB users using the graph api and getting back their name etc., however I'm trying to extract their location but its always nil. 
I've tried various different ways to extract but its always nil.

I don't think its a case of the user's not having set their location because if I search some random name and get back hundreds of results, then I'm unable to obtain the location for any of them.

Here's one example of how I've attempted to obtain the location:

```
NSString* graphRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"search?q=%@&type=user", person];
FBRequest *fbRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath: graphRequest];

[fbRequest startWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *theError)
 {
     if (theError)
     {
         // handle error
     }
     else
     {
         NSDictionary<FBGraphObject> *dict = (NSDictionary<FBGraphObject> *) result;
         if (dict)
         {
             NSArray *data = [dict objectForKey:@"data"];
             if (data)
             {
                 for (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *searchResult in data)
                 {
                     // here searchResult has valid data for the id and name etc.

                     id<FBGraphPlace> fbPlace = [searchResult location];
                     // but here fbPlace is nil

                     id<FBGraphLocation> fbLocation = [fbPlace location];
                     NSString *userCity = [fbLocation city];
                     NSString *userCountry = [fbLocation country];
                     NSString *name = fbPlace.name;

                 }
         }
     }
 }];
```

I've tried extracting the location with variants of the above, for example:

```
FBGraphObject<FBGraphPlace> *place = (FBGraphObject<FBGraphPlace>*)searchResult.location;
```

But no matter what I do, its always nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the field location is not included in the public profile. Field location is protected by a permission "user_location". However even if you required an access token with this permission it will only allow viewing location of the app user.
You can try it out on Facebook Graph API Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

1. Tap on "Get Access Token" and confirm that you have "user_location" permission
2. Search for your name and surname (separate them by space or %20) and ask for location field (something like this `search?type=user&fields=id,name,picture,location&q=John%20Doe`)
3. Confirm that in the list of the users only your user has the location (if you've set it up)

There is however an option also to see the **locations of app user friends**. In that case you must use v1.0 API (which will be discontinued after [April 30th, 2015](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)) and obtain an access token with a permission friends_location.

You can confirm this too on [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) :

1. Tap on version switching button on top right and choose v1.0
2. Tap on "Get Access Token", tab Friends Data Permissions and confirm that you have "friends_location" permission
3. Search for your friend which has setup his/her location and you'll notice that you can see it in the results.
4. Switch API to v2.0 and try the search again - location is not in the results anymore

So the conclusion is - location is accessible only for the user of your app (access token) and his/her friends (if you use v1.0 API which are be discontinued after less than a year).